# ObjectID issue in prisma with mongodb. It's not 12 bytes

Tags: mongodb, prisma, sveltekit

I am using sveltekit, prisma, lucia, mongodb in my project. While creating new user from lucia, I get error.

```
PrismaClientKnownRequestError:  
Invalid prisma.user.create() invocation:
Malformed ObjectID: provided hex string representation must be exactly 12 bytes, instead got: "Dw1LEILpEUHbZPi", length 15 for the field 'id'.
```

Code to create user.

```
const user = await auth.createUser({
                key: {
                    providerId: 'email', // auth method
                    providerUserId: email, // unique id when using "email" auth method
                    password // hashed by Lucia
                },
                attributes: {
                    email: email.toLowerCase(),
                    unique_user_url: uniqueURL,
                }
            });
            const session = await auth.createSession({
                userId: user.userId,
                attributes: {}
            });
            locals.auth.setSession(session); // set session cookie
```

Can't find a way to make that id 12 Bytes.

Comment: Where did "Dw1LEILpEUHbZPi" come from?

Comment: It's auto generated in prisma with " id @default(auto()) map("_id") @db.ObjectId "

Comment: That's strange, an ObjectID is 12 bytes, which would be 24 hexadecimal digits, or 16 base-64 characters.  Perhaps check to see that nothing is trimming any characters from that.

Comment: yes, and prisma automatically map _id of mongodb. Can't figure out why it's generating such id.

Comment: I suspect it generated a 16-character base-64 string, but one of the characters got trimmed or dropped somehow.  I can't really be more specific without seeing any code.